# loop over an array of page url's in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs, I am trying to build an app which has 10 pages and a user goes from one page to another while swiping to left.I just want to know how to write the logic in angularjs. For example, if a user is on the third page, if he swipes left he goes to 4th page and if he swipes right he goes to 2nd page.Can anyone please help? Thank You!

I have set up all routes, controllers and views for all the pages. Here's my swipe.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myElement = document.getElementById('first');
var hammer    = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
var swipe     = new Hammer.Swipe();

hammer.add(swipe);

hammer.on('swipeleft', function(){
        window.location = '#/exhibits';
});

hammer.on('swiperight', function(){
    window.location = '#/pavilion';
});
});
```

Since a swipe event should be on a body according to me, i put the "id='first'"
on the body element. This works perfectly fine but how should i navigate through multiple pages.A snippet of my app.js file:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'mm.foundation']);

  myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^s*(https?|file|ms- appx):/);
 }]);


  myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        title : 'WELCOME',
        templateUrl: 'pages/homepage/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/pavilion', {
        title : "AT A GLANCE : PAVILION OVERVIEW ",
        templateUrl: 'pages/pavilion/pavilion.html',
        controller: 'PavilionController'
    }).
    when('/exhibits', {
        title : 'AT A GLANCE : EXHIBITS OVERVIEW',
        templateUrl: 'pages/exhibits/exhibits.html',
        controller: 'ExhibitsController'
```

Comment: There is quite a bit of work required here.  Without some code and maybe a plunkr to work from, there is a long way to go.  To far for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created those 10 views, and have provided the needed routing, to provide the swipe functionality, Angular provides angular-touch. You can use ngTouch and its event to provide swipe functionality.
More can be found at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch